# Gradle application plugin start scripts template with custom variables

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to customize the start scripts generated by `application` plugin and  can't find the API  to pass my custom variables to default `TemplateBasedScriptGenerator` used by `startScripts` task.
If it doesn't exist, what is the workaround ?
Thanks